# REST API - Authentication vs Authorisation?

Tags: api, rest, authentication, oauth

I am creating some APIs and I am confused about how my application will authenticate, basically because I feel I need 2 authentications and I cannot find any information about this.

1. Authentication with the API Server (so my app will be able to retrieve data and sync even if no user is logged in)
2. Users authentication

Is one endpoint (i.e. /login ) enough to manage all this?

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: You are talking authentication vs authorization. Authentication is stating that you are who are you are. Authorization is asking if you have access to a certain resource.

Comment: Thanks @Doug, I start to understand......! If you have any example of implementation would be very appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot give you an example because I am not sure what language you are using. If I remember correctly, Visual Studio has an OAuth example as the sample MVC project. In Rails, you would check the users privileges in the Controller. In a former project, I used an HMAC to  authenticate with the gem Api-Auth. If you are doing it in Django, the official Django tutorial has examples as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am just designing the APIs for now so I don't know what language will be used for it, my need is to understand the logic behind only

Answer (score 0):

In this case, use an HMAC on the incoming request with a preshared key to authenticate the user. Then on your resource (in the Controller), validate that your user is authorized to access the route.

Comment: but how can I authenticate the app to use the APIs when the user is not logged in?